# Java error: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.google.gson.JsonObject

Tags: java, mongodb

I trying to insert the below document to a mongo collection, but I am getting an error called

Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.google.gson.JsonObject

Value of docObj

```
Document{{files=[Document{{filename=newfile2018-04-25_03-32-01, filedata=[],     unalloccount=0}}], employeelist=[{"employeeid":"employee0","datacount":1}], status=new, seq=0, _id=jobs0}}
```

jobDetails has the value

```
{"jobname":"dfd","filelist":["newfile2018-04-25_03-32-01"],"employeelist":[{"employeeid":"employee0","datacount":1}]}
```

My Java Code looks like below:

```
public String createJob(String appCode, JsonObject jobDetails) {
    Document job = new Document();
    Document fileObj = new Document();
    List<Document> fileDataList = null;
    List<Document> fileList = new ArrayList<Document>();
    System.out.println(jobDetails);
    for (JsonElement file : (JsonArray) jobDetails.get("filelist")) {
        fileObj = new Document();
        fileDataList = copyFileDataToJob(appCode, file.getAsString());
        fileObj.put("filename", file.getAsString());
        fileObj.put("filedata", fileDataList);
        fileObj.put("unalloccount", fileDataList.size());
        fileList.add(fileObj);
    }
    job.put("files", fileList);
    job.put("employeelist",jobDetails.get("employeelist"));
    job.put("status", "new");
    insertObject(appCode, "jobs", job, null);
    return null;
}

public String insertObject(String appCode, String collName, Document docObj, Map<String, Object> specificParams) {
    JsonObject returnObj = new JsonObject();
    MongoClient cli = ProfManDBFactory.getMongoClient();
    MongoDatabase db = cli.getDatabase(appCode);
    MongoCollection<Document> table = db.getCollection(collName);
    int nextSeq = getNextSequence(db, collName);
    docObj.put("seq", nextSeq);
    docObj.put("_id", collName + nextSeq);
    System.out.println(docObj);
    System.out.println(docObj.getClass().getName());
    if (specificParams != null) {
        docObj.putAll(specificParams);
    }
    >//ERROR OCCURS IN THIS LINE.
    table.insertOne(docObj);
    returnObj.addProperty(RS_STATUS, MSG_SUCCESS);
    returnObj.addProperty(RS_APPCODE, appCode);
    return returnObj.toString();
}
```